# Grapple doesn't work in Zelda Wind Waker

Tags: emulation, zelda-wind-waker, dolphin-emulator

**Problem**
For some reason my grapple has never quite worked in Wind Waker.

The only way I can latch on is by aiming very high above the grapple zones.

**Solution?**

Has anybody ever seen this problem before? If so, how did you fix it?

See video:

I can't for the life of me work out why it wouldn't be working correctly. I am using the Dolphin emulator 3.5.

Answer (score 9):

I'm playing Wind Waker on Dolphin too - and I haven't had a hint of this problem before. So have hope! You're not (completely) doomed!

A couple of things - first of all, the video you posted shows a *ridiculously* low framerate. If I'm not mistaken, that's evidence that you're using a built-in graphics card.

Surprisingly enough, a Gamecube can't really be emulated on a built-in graphics card - notwithstanding the fact that it's 12 years old - because like all gaming systems, the graphics card was the most powerful piece of hardware in there. I'd recommend getting a $50 graphics card from your local Best Buy - they're super-easy to install, and if it still doesn't work, you can return it within 14 days for a full refund.

Secondly, the way that your aim is sort of 'bouncing' in the video shows me that you're using a keyboard to play. Uh-uh. Ain't gonna cut it. That bounce is only exacerbating the glitch, and it's gonna kill you for the rest of the game. Luckily, this is solved even more easily - get a gamepad (you know, a controller) for 15$ from Target. Presto, your very own Gamecube/N64/PS/PS2/Whatever-system-you-ever-choose-to-emulate controller!

Thirdly, yeah, I realize that this question is two months old. You've probably already given up on your computer, bought that VGA adapter, beat Wind Waker, moved on to Twilight Princess, and started a fanfic novel about Link's unrequited love for Midna. But this is also for all those out there who download an emulator, boot up a game, and then go "Huh. This really isn't any fun." Because it should be fun.

Give me a few more paragraphs and I can tie this in with the American Dream, but let's just leave it at that for now. :D

Comment: heh thanks for the reply. I've still got the game open, but indeed I'm not playing it much :( But in reply to question :p 1 & 2 are incorrect. My PC's a mammoth, SLI linked up 590's the low frame rate comes from the way i recorded the video :p. I've got a xbox 360 controller for PC. Oddly enough, when i use the keyboard I don't have this problem, grrrr. I believe its something to do with the sticks and their positiong :( arghhhhh i love this game! I can't go on and play the next 2 zelda games as well :p

Comment: Huh. Well, I tried. I use a Logitech Dualshock gamepad; maybe try a different gamepad and see if that helps?

Comment: :D i appreciate it hugely. Not a bad idea, but i spent £40 on this little bad boy :p I may give it a go, you got your settings for dolphin? I wonder if i might steal them from u/

Comment: no? no settings then

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed you asking me for the settings completely somehow. I don't have em right this sec, but I'll get em to you tonight.

Comment: Or not. I seem to have accidentally deleted my Dolphin emulator...

Comment: Boooooo :p So basically I found no solution for this, using the windows game pad does not work

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I had the same issue when emulating Wind Waker - I just presumed it was BECAUSE it was emulated (maybe i'm right) and played this way.

It could just be an unfortunate and very irritating glitch

Comment: nooooo!!!! Thats not the answer I wanted to hear :) I did buy the game for the game cube... but i don't want to sit in my front room playing it..

Comment: @Jamie Move the console to your computer monitor and get a VGA adapter?

Comment: Interesting.. I do have two hdmi inputs on my monitor... I'll look on ebay

Comment: I'll loose my saves though, that's annoying.